# What's the difference between using Iterator and for loop for a vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, iterator

I would like to find out the difference between this code:

```
Vertices {
int x;
int y;
};

vector<Vertices>point;
Vertices min1,max1;

i = point.begin();

min1.y = i->y;
min1.x = i->x;
max1.x = i->x;

i++;

if(i->x < min1.x)
{
    min1.x = i->x;
}
else
{
    max1.x = i->x;
}
```

and this code:

```
min1.y = point[0].y;
min1.x = point[0].x;
max1.x = point[0].x;    
for (int i = 1; i < point.size(); i++) {
        if (point[i].x < min1.x)
            min1.x = point[i].x;
        else
            max1.x = point[i].x;
    }
```

**EDIT**
I have added in why for the 2nd piece of code to iterate from the 2nd element. What I'm doing is to compare and get the largest and smallest values. What I don't get it is why do they give me 2 different set of values? Am I misunderstanding something wrong?

Comment: Iterators is a generalized abstraction for pointers. By themselves, they don't automatically loop through a container.

Comment: I guess you mean for your first code sample to be inside a loop?

Comment: The first example has no loop, the second one does.

Comment: @greatwolf well if I'm getting the 1st code snippet right, it only runs through the 2nd element and gets the big n small `x` by comparing from the first to the second element. Then why doesn't the 2nd code snippet work in the same way and get the same result since it runs through the vector and compares `x` against each element?

Answer (score 4):

First difference is that you don't have a **loop** in first case. It treats only very first element.

Second difference is that you **start from 1** when you have a 0-th element in the second case. It treats all elements except very first.

Even with iterator you has to have a loop. The difference between using and not using iterators is just a convenience. Iterators are just different interface to access elements in a vector.

Comment: You fixed second error, but your first problem is still present, you don't have loop there.

Comment: SO i'm right to say that the 1st code snippet only access the 1st and 2nd element of the vector? Then how come it gives me the correct values when the result can also be achieved with the 2nd code snippet?

Comment: You are right. Well. Are you sure that your test arrays are good enough? What is happening in other parts of your code? Can you post all of it?

Answer (score 1):

The iterator `std::vector<typename>::iterator itr` starts at the beginning of the vector, which is by default the first value of of your `std::vector<typename> myVector`.

When using a array you should start off with the very first element which is `[0]` not `[1]`.

And here's a short example (out of my code) of using a iterator in a for loop:

```
void Rep_C_F_in_Ex (std::vector<std::string> *vTestTwo)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vTestOne_;
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator itr = vTestTwo->begin(); itr != vTestTwo->end(); itr++)
    {
        boost::split_regex (vTestOne_, *itr, boost::regex (",") );

        for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator iterate = vTestOne_.begin(); iterate != vTestOne_.end(); iterate++)
        {
            vTestThree.push_back (*iterate);
            ++iterate;
            vTestFour.push_back (*iterate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't state my question properly. Perhaps you could look at it again? Thanks

Comment: Could you post some more code e.g. what `min1`, `max1`, `x` and `y` is ?

Comment: One more thing. Your iterator is `vector<Vertices>::iterator i;` right ?

Comment: IMO, they should give you both the same output, as `min1.x = i->x;` == `min1.x = point[i].x;`.

Comment: Yeah i agree. but for some reason it isn't. That's what I'm trying to find out. The 1st code snippet gives the correct values but the second doesn't. That's puzzling.

Comment: Have you tried using a `iterator` in the for loop ? Like my code above. I haven't been using a integer for this yet.

Comment: yes i have. it gives the same result as in the second snippet. Weird isn't it?

Comment: Strange, try to debug it, look into it what goes where wrong. You have the whole code... the only way I know ATM. I don't see any error in this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop it as array, you should start from 0 instead of 1.

```
int i = 0;
```

Bettor write it as below:

```
for (std::vector<xxx>::iterator it = point.begin(); it != point.end; ++it)
```